# Make quinoa sticky like rice?

Tags: rice, presentation, quinoa

I make a nice curry, and for presentation I would like to place the quiona on top of curry as shown in this picture: [image: rice on top of curry]

But to be able to do that, my quiona needs to be sticky (I think it's the starch in the rice that allows it to hold its shape)

Any of you cooking geniuses can think of a way that I can have my quinoa hold its shape without affecting the flavor greatly?

Edit: My standard cooking technique, is to wash the quinoa thoroughly (I'm told this is a necessity), then simmer in two parts water to one part Quinoa.

Comment: Can you tell us, in the question, how you are cooking/preparing your quinoa?

Comment: Standard cooking process. Wash first, then boil in two parts water to one part Quinoa. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could... maybe add some starch?

Comment: Like add a touch of flour maybe? Maybe toast that flour a little to give it some flavour?

Answer (score 2):

Cook it as usual nice and fluffy.

No one appreciates doughy quinoa.

Two choices:

A.at holding-temp, weigh down with a plate to just fit inside pan. scoop out servings carefully.

B. when just finished cooking. pack into ramekins etc tightly and rewarm. oiling may be necessary for ease of release.

Answer (score 1):

To make it sticky, I would cook it with coconut milk.

Try with different ratio of water and coconut milk to get the perfect consistency and taste (to you).

Comment: Next week I'll give it a try. Will report back my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, i was just googling the opposit. I was so happy to buy cheaper quinoa a costco (ottawa) yesterday and they have this new brand from canada. It happens to be "glutinous" quinoa. Best for hot dishes as it sticks. It was great in mexican food but not the best in my salad since i prefer dry quinoa in salads. I'm not sure where you are from but if you can get your hands on it, it would make the ball in the picture. I can send you a picture of the bag if you want.
I use my instant pot to make it but the bag says to simply boil it like pasta.

Comment: You said that you found quinoa that cooked up sticky, but how can the OP (original post) find the same or similar? What kind of quinoa was it? Or did the packaging state that it "sticky"? Or, did you acheive this by your cooking method?

Answer (score 0):

While the quinoa is still steamy hot, use an ice cream scoop to portion out "balls", packing as much inside as you can.